# Export azure policies inside a initiative with CLI?

Tags: azure, powershell, command-line-interface, azure-policy

I am trying to export all the assigned policies from MG scope. I am retrieving correctly te policies and the initiatives that are assigned but I'm not able to find a solution to export also the policies that are inside the assigned initiative.

```
Get-AzPolicyAssignment |
    Select-Object -ExpandProperty properties |
    Select-Object -Property DisplayName, Scope, PolicyDefinitionID |
    Where-Object { $_.Scope -like "/providers/Microsoft.Management/managementGroups/MG-name*" } |
    Export-Csv -Path "./policyAssignments.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```

I wanna know if there is a way to do it or I am just wasting time.

Answer (score 0):

> Export azure policies inside a initiative with CLI

AFAIK, you can only get the initiatives and not the Policies inside it using PowerShell:
But you can get the initiatives in a particular management  Group:

```
$x=Get-AzPolicySetDefinition
foreach($y in $x)
{
foreach($e in  $y.PolicySetDefinitionId)
{
$v=$e -like "*managementGroups/XXX*"
if($v){
$y
}
}
}
```

**`managementGroups/XXX`**  is part of the id which initiatives have in a particular management group.
**`Get-AzPolicySetDefinition`** is used to Get Initiatives

**`Output:`**

[image]

Then you can use   `Export-Csv`  command to export this information.

Comment: Hello, thank you your response. I figured out how to export the initiatives too but what i wanted to check was if there is an actual way of retrieving the policies inside the assigned initiatives. As far as I researched it doesn't seems possible.

Comment: Yes, that is what I figured out.